# Passing around "this" context in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this the right way of doing things. Also here i am passing around `this` context via **_this** is there a better way of doing it

```
var messages = {
    getLoadMore : function(_this){
        ...............
    },

    getSwappingData : function(_this){
        .................
    },
}

jQuery('.js-message-swap').live('click', function(){
    _this = jQuery(this);
    messages.getSwappingData(_this);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You do not necessarily need `_this = jQuery(this);` just pass it as an argument directly.

Comment: FYI, `.live()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work fine. A shorter version would be to pass the reference of the function to the `click` handler, which will then apply `this` to the external function. Try this:

```
var messages = {
    getLoadMore : function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        return false;
    },

    getSwappingData : function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        return false;
    }
}

jQuery('.js-message-swap').live('click', messages.getSwappingData);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `in the constructor`?

Comment: classes do, however these are functions, so unfortunately you can't

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to do it is pass it as an argument to the function instead of a variable.

```
var messages = {
    getLoadMore : function(_this){
        ...............
    },

    getSwappingData : function(_this){
        .................
    },
}

jQuery('.js-message-swap').live('click', function(){
    // Remove this _this = jQuery(this);
    messages.getSwappingData(jQuery(this));
    return false;
});
```